# How to do nested populate in mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

My project involves me to allow only a `school Admin` to insert data of the students for the respective schools and I should display the details of the `school Admin` who inserted the data with the student details he entered.

My schema for the `students` schema is as follows:

```
    userId: {
        type: Object,
        ref: 'User'
    },
    ugId:{
        type:Number

    },
    firstName:{
        type:String,
        required:true
    },
    lastName:{
       type:String,
       required:true    
    }
```

Here you can see that the `userId` is referring to model called `User` whose schema is as follows:

```
    email: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        index: true,
        unique: true
    },
    firstName: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    lastName: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    userName: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    password: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    mappedUserDetails2: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Students'
    },
    UserGroupID: {
        type: Object,
        ref: 'UserGroups'
    }
```

In the User Schema, `UserGroupID` is referring into `UserGroups` Model whose schema is as follows:

```
 groupName: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        index: true,
        unique: true
    },
    createdDate: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    },
    updatedDate: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    },
    uid: {
        type: Number,
        min: 1
    },
    mappedUserDetails3: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'User'
    }
```

The Data I posted is as follows

```
{
  "userId":"55b7320173ceb5640e1b24a6",
  "ugId":3,
  "firstName":"AGGI",
  "lastName":"AGGIqa"
}
```

The Output I received on successful completion of my API is as follows

```
 { 
  "success": true,
  "userData":{
             "_id": "55b758a09472f03310cdb9a2",
             "userId":{
                 "_id": "55b7320173ceb5640e1b24a6",
                 "email": "XYZ@gmail.com",
                 "firstName": "XYZ",
                 "lastName": "XYZ",
                 "userName": "XYZ XYZ",
                 "UserGroupID": "55b7138c049d0d5d0dddd824",
                 "__v": 0
                },
              "firstName": "AGGI",
              "lastName": "AGGIqa",
              "ugId": 3,
              "__v": 0
}
```

**`My Question`**:I want to know that is there a way to populate the `UserGroupID` in an already populated `userId` as the `UserGroupID` is referring to an `objectId` of the `UserGroup` Model?

My `populate` code for the `userId` is as follows:

```
    Students.findOne({
                    _id: data._doc._id
                }).populate('userId','-password').exec(function (err, data) {
                    if (err) {
                        return res.json({
                            success: false,
                            exception: err
                        });
                    }
                    else{ 
                    return res.json({
                            success: true,
                            userData: data
                        });
                    }
                });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mongoose doesn't provide this feature by default but you can [write your own plugin](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/plugins.html) otherwise you can use [mongoose-deep-populate](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongoose-deep-populate) which does exactly what you need.

Comment: Thanks for the info.. it helped a lot